# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - How do we generate .ipa file?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 to develop Hybrid Application development.

How do we generate .ipa file so that we can deploy on to an ios device and test our Application?

Note: We don't have any MAC OS.

Comment: You must have a Mac to generate an .ipa. Apple restrict .ipa generation so you can only use their hardware. MobileFirst Platform has no way to circumvent this restriction.

Answer (score 4):

To generate an .ipa file you must use a Mac with Xcode installed in it.
Xcode is the only supported method by IBM (and by Apple) to generate an .ipa file.

This is described in the training materials. See these tutorials:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-mobilefirst-development-environment/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-ios-development-environment/

Get a Mac. :)